# MySql query inner join when is not null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Query with the following statements:

if table2.data is not null:  `table1.id = table2.id and table2.data = table1.data`

but if table2.data null: = `table1.id = table2.id` (without 'data')

```
    select * from table1
    inner join table2
if 'data' null or 'data' blank
    on table1.id = table2.id
if 'data' nut null or 'data' not blank
    on table1.id = table2.id and table2.data = table1.data
```

i found very good solution to use: `COALESCE` mysql function

Answer (score 0):

You want to do like this..!!??

```
 select * from table1
 inner join table2
 on table1.id = table2.id and table2.date = table1.date
 where table2.date is not null or table2.date != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id AND table2.date = table1.date
WHERE table2.date IS NOT NULL table2.date != ''
```

Using `OR` in the `WHERE` condition will make it always true (date is never `NULL` and `''`).

Comment: this way if date is null, it return 0 result, i want to remove this - 'AND table2.date = table1.date' if date field is empty

Comment: Probably you're looking for a `LEFT JOIN`? It's not really clear from your question...